# PDO Can't find data if clause 'where like' is used

Tags: php, sql, pdo, where-clause

I want to get some data from an MSSQL DB using the pdo class and using where like % % clause

I want to find username: mozzey0410

If i search only mozzey04 or mozzey041 i can find it. But if i try to use the full name: mozzey0410 no records given.
How to fix this? i want to search a full or partial name using the same query.

```
$user2 = $db->prepare("Select top 100 memb_guid,memb___id,mail_addr,Gender,Country from MEMB_INFO where memb___id like ? and mail_addr like ?");
$user2->bindValue(1, $userid . '%');
$user2->bindValue(2, $mail . '%');
$user2->execute();
$user = $user2->fetchall();
```

Comment: You said you want to use `WHERE .... LIKE '% %'` but in your query you are using `WHERE ..... LIKE ' '`

Comment: Hmm, how to fix it? i'm using the % in the bindvalue

If i use 2 % % will find me only the mozzey04, if i use only % at the end will find me all except mozzey0410

Comment: You cannot use operators in bindValue, that's the idea of binding a Value/Param ... it binds it as a certain param, i.e. in your case string (which protects you from sql injections, otherwise you could not only inject `%`, but also a ` ' `). You might want to use `WHERE memb__id LIKE concat('%', ?, '%')`

Comment: Using concat('%', ?, '%') doesn't give me any results, even if i search mozzey

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$user2 = $db->prepare("Select top 100 memb_guid,memb___id,mail_addr,Gender,Country from MEMB_INFO where memb___id like concat('%',?,'%') and mail_addr like ?");
```

and bind the value without '%'

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just prepend and append `wildcard` to your variable

```
$user2->bindValue(1, '%' . $userid . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$user2->bindValue(2, '%' . $mail . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Otherwise you can do something different using names instead of placeholders

```
$user2 = $dbh->prepare('Select top 100 memb_guid,memb___id,mail_addr,Gender,Country from MEMB_INFO where memb___id like :userid and mail_addr like :mail');

$userid = "%".$userid ."%";
$mail= "%".$mail."%";

$user2->bindParam(':userid', $userid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$user2->bindParam(':mail', $mail, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Comment: This only find me
mozzey0 and mozzey04 .
Can't find mozzey041 or mozzey0410

Comment: Same for the 2nd solution only can find mozzey0 and mozzey04 . Can't find mozzey041 or mozzey0410

Comment: @MandoMadalin what if you change `and mail_addr like` to `or mail_addr like` maybe there is none that matches both condition

Comment: I already did that, using only memb___id without mail_addr give me same :P even if i put or/and same.

Comment: @Mando i don't know if you understood me, what i was saying is `$user2 = $dbh->prepare('Select top 100 memb_guid,memb___id,mail_addr,Gender,Country from MEMB_INFO where memb___id like :userid OR mail_addr like :mail');`

Comment: @Mando Did you give it a try?

Comment: Yep, i did this, i even removed the mail_addr condition, and same :( can't find if i search for full name

Comment: Can u test on any database using a same query to see if there is same? it might be a pdo bug?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31754/discussion-between-fabio-and-mando-madalin)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found the problem:

The length of my column search (memb___id) was 10, i changed to 16 and works now!
So it was all about column length.